# Document library: Open with Explorer is suddenly starting OneDrive

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, open-with-explorer, onedrive

Some of our users have reported that a SharePoint document library is suddenly opening the current folders' files through OneDrive instead of opening the entire document library in a Windows Explorer screen. I have tested this out and I can confirm that this is occuring for multiple users, on multiple machines and multiple SharePoint sites.

This causes our users not being able to navigate through multiple folders in the document library which, for them, is a huge time save. As you can see in the screenshot below the command has just created a temporary folder on the hard drive instead of directly connecting to SharePoint.

[image: File explorer not connected to SharePoint, local temp folder]

Could someone please tell me how I can stop OneDrive from opening when this option is selected or how I should format the URL to be able to access the document library straight from Windows Explorer?

If anything is unclear, please let me know and I will update to clarify.

Comment: Are you using new experience in the SharePoint online library and still able to access the "Open with Explorer" option ?

Comment: @yash.kamdar I have tried both the new and classical experience but I get the same result with both of the options.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below steps to solve the issue:

1.Close all windows and programs

2.Start menu > Services > restart Webclient > close Services window

3.Start menu > Internet options > Advanced > Reset IE

If the issue still exists,open the File Explore and copy the document library address (something like: https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/siteURL/Shared%20Documents) directly to check whether you could access it.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but unfortunately it did not work, copying the exact address from the webpage does work but not consistently. It happens quite often that the explorer window will display an empty folder when navigating to the document library